# SQL script is not executed during startup

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I want to run SQL script always when I start Spring boot application. I added this Liquibase configuration:

***application.yml***

```
spring:
  datasource:
    platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
    url: jdbc:postgresql://10.10.10.10:5432/test
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: root
    password: test
  liquibase:
    changeLog: 'classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml'
    dropFirst: false
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    database: postgresql
```

***db.changelog-master.yaml***

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: db/changelog/changes/ch_0001/changelog.yaml
```

***changelog.yaml***

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
      file: db/changelog/changes/ch_0001/data/data.yaml
```

***data.yaml***

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 0001
      author: test
      dbms: postgres
      runAlways: true # WARNING - remove this before prod - it will run every time with clean data
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            - relativeToChangelogFile: true
            - path: data.sql
```

***data.sql***

```
INSERT into tasks SELECT generate_series(1,355) AS id,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS business_name,
    (select NOW() + (random() * (NOW()+'90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS created_at,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS meta_title,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS status,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS title,
    left (md5(random()::text), 10) AS task_type,
    (select NOW() + (random() * (NOW()+'90 days' - NOW())) + '30 days') AS updated_at;
```

Database table should be populated with test data but it's not. I don't see into logs data.sql file execution.

Do you know know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you did not add full config.

Try adding these.

```
spring:
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml
    url: {same as spring.datasource.url}
    user: {same as spring.datasource.username}
    password: {same as spring.datasource.password}
    enabled: true
```

#### Update

For Postgres DB `dbmd` value is `postgresql`. Not `postgres`.
Reference - [Here](https://www.liquibase.org/get-started/databases)  ​

Updated `data.yml`

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: 0001
      author: test
      dbms: postgresql
      runAlways: true # WARNING - remove this before prod - it will run every time with clean data
      changes:
        - sqlFile:
            - relativeToChangelogFile: true
            - path: data.sql
```

Comment: Are you sure hat it should be `change-log` not `changeLog`?

Comment: I tested it but still no change.

Comment: @PeterPenzov I have used it as `change-log` without issue.

Comment: @PeterPenzov did liquebase tables were created in your DB?

Comment: yes, tables are created but I think by Hibernate

Comment: What do you mean by 'update new app.yml'?

Comment: I mean `application.yml` after you added the configs I have mentioned. Don't replace your current one, add as an appendix. Liquebase also crate two tables to maintain changelog history? are they created? If you are creating tables by via liquebase changelog, set `ddl-auto: none`

Comment: I added `ddl-auto: none` but still not working..... Other ideas?

Comment: Excellent! Thant was the issue.